# Stopping automatic compilation

Tags: compiling, texstudio, auto-completion

As I stop writing in Texstudio, the compiler automatically starts compilation. I don't even need to press `F6` button. Sometimes this is very uncomfortable. How do I stop auto compilation?

P.S: I have unchecked `Auto complete parentheses`<< `Adv. Editor` and `Automatically start completer when typing LaTeX-commands`<<`completion`.

Comment: Isn't that a question for the maintainers of TexStudio?

Comment: May be. But I thought if any sort of help is available from here...

Comment: Usually we try to stick to answering TeX questions only. The various editors and IDE's have their own forums for dealing with their inner workings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are talking about is not auto-completion, but auto-compilation.

You can disable that by unchecking `Auto-recompile document on changes` under `Internal PDF Viewer`

[image]

Auto-completion is the feature that helps you input commands in the editor - which I wouldn't disable. Automatically having parentheses closed is also very useful IMO.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Suddenly it drew my attention to the fact that what I was doing was not disabling auto compilation. From nowhere I could get this information.

Comment: You can turn both features back on and enjoy those useful features, without worrying about the problem you described ;)

Comment: But somehow the compiler takes different time to compile for the same document. Currently I am observing that the compiler has been compiling for more than 5 minutes and still continuing but the same document, it compiled at a glimpse of my eye sometime before. Why is it happening?